Pydub library has an error with version check
I am just curious why only this library has an error of version check.
Below is the code.
import pydub
print('Pydub version: ', pydub.__version__)

I got the error as below.
AttributeError: module 'pydub' has no attribute '__version__'

Other libraries can print their versions.
I could check the version(0.25.1) of 'pydub' by just installing it in prompt as below.
pip install pydub

Are there anyone who know the reason of an error of version check for 'Pydub'?

Nothing requires maintainer to provide dunder version. Even documentation for packaging does not say providing version is  either mandatory or even the only way. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/ . so there is no error here except your expectation that every python package provides version  to be present.

Thanks for your reply. I understand it.

If you really want the version, you can get it using pkg_resouces.get_distribution. Since __version__ is not actually required by anything, you should also treat it as not necessarily correct in the general case.

Alternatively you can get package version from the subprocess - use something like this:
import subprocess
import re

completed = subprocess.run(["pip", "show", "pydub"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8")
text = completed.stdout

res = re.search("Version: ([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)", text)
version = res.group(1)

Or alternatively call the pip from the python:
from pip._internal.commands import show

tt= show.search_packages_info(['pydub'])

for pkg in tt:
    print (pkg.name)
    print (pkg.metadata_version)
    print (pkg.version)

